# Transistor cross reference with pinout

Tags: npn, component-selection

I need to find a replacement transistor.  The only number I have to go by is a manufacturer (of the unit, not the transistor) part number from 1974 which of course leads nowhere.  I know it's a silicon NPN TO-220 case used as a relay driver.  I know the voltages, I can estimate the current, so I can search for all those parameters but get hundreds of candidates. Is there a way to further narrow down the field to just those with an EBC pinout without having to click through to every single data sheet?

Comment: Do you really *need* any special properties? Sounds like the properties aside from current and voltage capacity and something like "needs at least mediocre current amplification" are all the specs you need – the original designer probably didn't "wisely" choose that transistor either, but used whatever was available. Try sorting by price, restricting by current capability, case and pinout, and use the cheapest one that fits.

Comment: Once you've selected the parameters which matter to you, sort by price then pick the 1st one which fits your pin-out requirements. Done.

Comment: "restricting by current capability, case and pinout" ... "1st one which fits your pin-out requirements."  And how do I determine that without having to click through every single data sheet?

Comment: My memory *just barely* remembers the TO-220AA and TO-220AB package from that period. If memory serves, my first ever observation of that package was in 1975. I thought they were "weird" packaging, as I was used to more of the TO-3 variety for power. But I think RCA made some NPN of that packaging around that time. I might start there. For example, the 2N5293-2N5298 were packaged that way and are NPN devices. I still have some "versawatt" transistors. The 2N5490-2N5497 would be another range. So if from RCA, look up VERSAWATT. I think those were the only TO-220 NPNs from RCA in 1975.

Comment: 2N5298 is indeed a TO-220 NPN, but is BCE.

Comment: @Duston I don't recall a single case where the base was in the center, back then. Not one, ever. But I don't have a global view and didn't have access to much from Japan at the time. NatSemi, RCA, Mot, ... not one of these had center-base, to my recollection.

Comment: @Duston One idea comes to mind to find one, though. Often, "for profit" Spice program suppliers (ORCAD, back in the day, for example) had spice models as well as layout pictures with pinout assignments. They would have comprehensive databases of BJT parts to make it easy to produce a schematic. You might consider gaining access to the BJT part library portions of a popular Spice (with schematic editing included, obviously) program and write a program to scan the files for the pinout you are looking for. Some included the package number, as well, as part of the model statement. Just a thought.

Comment: @Duston it's not like you'll have to click through thousands of datasheets. More, like, 5, until you find a transistor that works. If you can't do it by the tenth datasheet, well, botch together something that crosses pins.

Comment: This is really interesting, which part had base in the centre?

Comment: https://www.vintageshifi.com/repertoire-pdf/pdf/telecharge.php?pdf=Fisher-332-Service-Manual.pdf That's a link to the service manual (PDF).  Page 6, Q953.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to fine tune your search parameters so that the candidate list is reduced. With reduced tight list you really only need to look at data sheets till you find a suitable part....no need to look at every part data sheet.

When considering that it is used as a relay driver do be careful to look at the driving circuit as well. There is a possibility that the component that you are looking to replace is a Darlington with a high current gain.

Comment: [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com) has a handy feature where you specify the parameters in multiple columns, which narrows down the suitable products for you.